# Echo data of nested array and break nested array after print every value in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 3 foreach loop and want to print value of nested third loop but want to break nested third loop after echo of every value.

Eg.

```
foreach($res1 as $value1){
  foreach($value1 as $value2){
    foreach($value3 as $value4){
      echo $value4;  // here i am getting value like: 012345
    }
  }
}
```

Means, I am getting value 012345 in one  but i want to print 0,1,2,3,4,5 in next td.

You can check link where I am getting problem:
https://www.chiczestuat.shop/product/signature-3-piece-owl-bracelet-limited-edition/

B clicking this link scroll bit down you will find.

[image]

Hope you understand.
Thanks

Comment: Can you share your all arrays so we fix it

Answer (score 0):

Use `break;` to stop the loops.

```
$res1 = [0 =>[0 => range(1,5), 1], 1];
foreach($res1 as $value1){
  foreach($value1 as $value2){
    foreach($value2 as $value4){
      echo $value4;  // here i am getting value like: 012345
    }
    break;
  }
  break;
}
```

Example:
https://3v4l.org/0epKY
I included a var_dump just to show what the array looks like.

---

An alternative way if to create a temporary array that you use to "dig" in to the array with key().

```
$res1 = [0 =>[0 => range(1,5), 1], 1];
$temp = $res1;
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
    $temp = $temp[key($temp)];
}

foreach($temp as $value4){
    echo $value4;  // here i am getting value like: 012345
}
```

https://3v4l.org/vURpf

I believe it will be quite eqaual in time, so choose the one you find easier to read.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas for your attention, but i want to run my this loop: 
foreach($value2 as $value4){
      echo $value4;  // here i am getting value like: 012345
    }
One time then want to come out from this loop and want to run upper loop and soo on. Please once see image. I will be very thankful to you. :)

Comment: @rohit13807 Tell me when you have edited your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve